# Input size vs hidden state in RNNs

Tags: neural-network, time-series, rnn, pytorch

Im using PyTorch to implement RNNs on **univariate time series data**. This is the documentation for the RNN class: [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html)

I think I'm understanding the math behind an RNN cell. But I have an specific question: if $x_t$ is a scalar (and not a vector) since I'm working with univariate time series, how can I perform the operation

$h_{t}=\tanh(x_{t}W_{ih}^{T}+b_{ih}+h_{t−1}W_{hh}^{T}+b_{hh})$ ?

My problem is that in this scenario I assume that $W_{ih}^{T}$ is a scalar (not a matrix) since $x_t$ is a scalar, but $h_{t-1}$ can be a vector (not a scalar) which implies that $h_{t−1}W_{hh}^{T}$ will be a vector, and how can I add a vector and a scalar!

Maybe the answer is simple: in this scenario a vector plus a scalar will be an entry-wise addition of the scalar. But I want to confirm with anyone that know more about the topic.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, can you please copy an example of your input so that we understand the problem better?

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 I'm dealing with a univariate time series. My data is of the form $[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1},x_n]$, where $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and the index $i$ is time. So the supervised approach to these type of problems is by having a features matrix $X$ of the form $[[x_1,x_2], [x_2,x_3], ..., [x_{n-2},x_{n_1}]]$ (we are using here two features or steps in the time series) and the response vector is $y$ of the form $[x_3,x_4,...,x_n]$. This is a good example of how it works: https://towardsdatascience.com/ml-approaches-for-time-series-4d44722e48fe

Comment: I appreciate that in the post you have share a windowing approach is used but a preprocessing step like that is only required for step-wise algorithms but not for RNN. You can work with a univariate input for any RNN layer in which case windowing is deemed redundant.